# sample size for classify

Tags: machine-learning

I was wondering how many pictures the classify function can process. It seems as soon as several hundred pictures are used for training the program freezes. Picture measurements are 1482x849 pixel and about 510 KB per picture. Pictures are preprocessed with ConformImages. If I split 500 pictures into 100 for training and 400 for testing I get no classifierfunction after processing a while. Am I missing something?

```
c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "RandomForest"];
```

Comment: It is heavily dependent upon the number of classes you use, computer specs, etc. From my experience, some `ClassifierFunction`s take more than 6+ hours to process. Just give your computer some time. You can `MemoryConstrain` just in case your computer runs out of memory.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Thx.

Comment: I meant `MemoryConstrained`. My bad.